# Как записать выражение или же его ОПЗ в дерево?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как записать в дерево выражение?
Нужно чтобы дерево было бинарным, а листья его числами, а не конечные узлы соответствовали математическим действиям:

1. (4+3)*(2-1)
2. Опз - 4 3 + 2 1 - * (если я правильно опз понял)
3. Надо преобразовать так чтобы * была корнем, потом слева был знак + а справа -, а на 3 уровне будут листья 4 3 потомки +, справа 2 1 потомки -.

Comment: Или возможно ли как то записать ОПЗ в массив двумерный? чтоб записывал в массив с конца, а потом в дерево записать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А где Ваш первый вопрос, где были примеры реализации алгоритма?

Еще раз: [Обратная польская запись: примеры реализации](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Вот хотя бы самый близкий пример на Си разберите. Ваше дерево можно собрать тут же, в стеке. В конце обработки выражения в этом стеке просто должен остаться 1 элемент. Если Вы правильно обработаете все нужные Вам операции с операндами, это и будет Ваше дерево.

Comment: Спасибо большое