# Как построить из ОПЗ бинарное дерево с++?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Вот пример реализации ОПЗ, возможно местами криво. Как из этого сделать бинарное дерево? У меня идея была построить двумерный массив и уже оттуда считать правда трудно получается.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;
//ОПЗ запись с++

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int i = 0, s = 0, e = 0, n1 = 0, v = 0, ch, s2 = 0;
    char vr[100], stek[100], exit[100];
    double stek2[100];
cout << "Введите выражение: \n";
cin >> vr;

for (i = 0; vr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    switch (vr[i])
{
    case '+':
        while ((s != 0) && (stek[s - 1] != '('))
        {
            exit[e] = stek[s - 1]; //на выход 
            e++;
            s--;
        }
        stek[s] = '+'; //в стек 
        s++;
        break;
    case '-':
        while ((s != 0) && (stek[s - 1] != '('))
        {
            exit[e] = stek[s - 1];
            e++;
            s--;
        }
        stek[s] = '-';
        s++;
        break;
    case '*':

        while ((s != 0) && (stek[s - 1] != '(') && (stek[s - 1] != '+') && (stek[s - 1] != '-'))
        {
            exit[e] = stek[s - 1];
            e++;
            s--;
        }
        stek[s] = '*';
        s++;
        break;
    case '/':

        while ((s != 0) && (stek[s - 1] != '(') && (stek[s - 1] != '+') && (stek[s - 1] != '-'))
        {
            exit[e] = stek[s - 1];
            e++;
            s--;
        }
        stek[s] = '/';
        s++;

        break;
    case '(':
    {
                stek[s] = '(';
                s++;
                break; }
    case ')':


        while ((stek[s - 1] != '(') && (s != 0))
        {
            exit[e] = stek[s - 1];
            e++;
            s--;
        }
        stek[s - 1] = ' ';
        s--;
        break;
    default:
    {
               exit[e] = vr[i];
               e++;
               if ((vr[i + 1] == '+') || (vr[i + 1] == '-') || (vr[i + 1] == '*') || (vr[i + 1] == '/') || (vr[i + 1] == '(') || (vr[i + 1] == ')'))
               {
                   exit[e] = ' ';
                   e++;
               }
    }
}

exit[e] = ' ';
e++;

while (s != 0)
{
    exit[e] = stek[s - 1];
    e++;
    s--;
}
cout << "ОПЗ ";
for (i = 0; i < e; i++)
{
    cout << exit[i];
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Или это АСД? я плохо разбираюсь в программировании, даже классы еще не начал изучать. Встретил идею делить на токены, но что это не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал более общий пример реализации ОПЗ из [Вашего предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757571/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%97-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) и [модифицировал](https://www.diffchecker.com/5wQyiD5u) его для построения дерева:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <vector>

#define STKDPTH 32 /* Глубина стека */

/* Значения, возвращаемые функцией parse */
#define VAL  0  /* В стек занесено новое значение */
#define ADD  1  /* Сложение */
#define SUB  2  /* Вычитание */
#define MUL  3  /* Умножение */
#define DIV  4  /* Деление */
#define SOF -1  /* Переполнение стека */
#define SUF -2  /* В стеке недостаточно операндов */
#define UNK -3  /* Неопознанное значение */

#define NODEBIT (size_t(1) << (sizeof(size_t) * 8 - 1))

struct node {
    size_t left;
    size_t right;
    int type;
    node(int type, size_t left, size_t right)
        : type(type), left(left), right(right)
    {
    }
};

/* Глобальные переменные */
int scount;
std::vector<node> tree;
std::vector<double> operands;
size_t stack[STKDPTH];

/* Функция распознавания аргументов */
int parse(char *);


/* Функция печати дерева */
void printTree();

/* Точка входа */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    /* Организуем цикл для перебора аргументов командной строки */
    while( *++argv ) {
        /* Пытаемся распознать текущий аргумент как число или
        * символ арифметической операции */
        int type = parse(*argv);
        switch( type ) {
        case VAL: continue;

            /* Вычисляем */
        case ADD:
        case SUB:
        case MUL:
        case DIV:
            tree.emplace_back(type, stack[scount - 1], stack[scount]);
            stack[scount - 1] = NODEBIT | (tree.size() - 1);
            break;

        /* Обработка ошибок */
        case SUF:
        fprintf(stderr, "Недостаточно операндов!\n");
        return(1);

        case SOF:
        fprintf(stderr, "Переполнение стека!\n");
        return(1);

        case UNK:
        fprintf(stderr, "Неопознанный аргумент!\n");
        return(1);
        }
    }

    /* Вывести результат */
    printTree();

    return(0);
}

int parse(char *s)
{
    double tval = 0;
    char * endptr;

    /* Распознаем знаки арифметических операций */
    switch( *s ) {
    case '-':
    /* Если минус является первым и не последним символом аргумента,
    * значит пользователь ввел отрицательное число и опознавать его
    * как операцию вычитания не нужно */
    if( *(s + 1) != '\0' ) break;
    if( scount >= 2 ) {
        scount -= 1;
        return(SUB);
    } else return(SUF);

    case '+':
    if( scount >= 2 ) {
        scount -= 1;
        return(ADD);
    } else return(SUF);

    case 'x':
    if( scount >= 2 ) {
        scount -= 1;
        return(MUL);
    } else return(SUF);

    case '/':
    if( scount >= 2 ) {
        scount -= 1;
        return(DIV);
    } else return(SUF);
    }

    errno = 0;

    /* Пытаемся сконвертировать строковый аргумент в число */
    tval = strtod(s, &endptr);

    /* Вернуть ошибку `неопознанный аргумент' в случае неудачи */
    if( errno != 0 || *endptr != '\0' ) return(UNK);

    /* Проверяем, есть ли свободное место в стеке
    * и сохраняем в нем операнд, иначе возвращаем ошибку переполнения */
    operands.push_back(tval);
    if( scount < STKDPTH ) stack[scount++] = operands.size() - 1;
    else return(SOF);

    return(VAL);
}

void printTree()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, int>> local;

    for( int i = 0; i < scount; i++ ) {
        local.emplace_back(stack[i], 0);
        while( !local.empty() ) {
            auto st = local.back();
            local.pop_back();

            // indent
            for( int i = st.second; i--; putc('\x20', stdout), putc('\x20', stdout) );

            if( (st.first & NODEBIT) != 0 ) {
                auto &n = tree[st.first & ~NODEBIT];
                local.emplace_back(n.right, st.second + 1);
                local.emplace_back(n.left, st.second + 1);
                switch( n.type ) {
                case ADD:
                    printf("+ (add)\n");
                    break;
                case SUB:
                    printf("- (sub)\n");
                    break;
                case MUL:
                    printf("x (mul)\n");
                    break;
                case DIV:
                    printf("/ (div)\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("unexpected\n");
                }
            } else {
                printf("%0.3f\n", operands[st.first]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь для операндов используется вектор `operands`, а для узлов дерева - вектор `tree`. В стеке хранятся индексы в эти векторы. А чтобы можно было их различать, я использую флаг `NODEBIT`.

**Пример:**

```
3 10 5 - +
```

**Результат:**

```
+ (add)
  3,000
  - (sub)
    10,000
    5,000
```